# Angular 8 set state from http with NgRx

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

**My Objective**: Update my service file with the 'NgRx' way of doing things.

I am making a GET request to fetch menu data from my service, as soon as that call occurs, I want it to set my 'menu' state in NgRx, so that I can access the menu data everywhere.

I'm not sure what the best way to approach this is.

My current code:

**Menu.service.ts**

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>) { }

  public getMenu(): Observable<Restaurant> {
    // not sure where to run this code:
    // this.store.dispatch(new MenuActions.SetMenu(menu));

    return this.http.get<Menu>('http://localhost:1234/api/menu');
  }
```

**Questions**:

1.) Is it best practice to dispatch the menu item in my service?

2.) Should I use the 'pipe' operator after the call is made to dispatch the update?

3.) If I'm using NgRx, I feel like I don't need to subscribe to `getMenu()`, since the state will be set in this file, and I can just access state where I'd normally subscribe to this service. Is using the service file here valid, or am I taking the wrong approach for ngrx? If this isn't correct, what is the alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: Save the headache of ngrx and do it a sane way, https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: You should use ngrx effects to handle the side effects - https://ngrx.io/guide/effects

Comment: pretty tempting @AdrianBran , it is a headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it best practice to dispatch the menu item in my service?

You can but I wouldnt recommend because NGRX has effect for that. Effect stand for side effect to do some logic calculation.

> Should I use the 'pipe' operator after the call is made to dispatch the update?

You should not.

> If I'm using NgRx, I feel like I don't need to subscribe to getMenu(), since the state will be set in this file, and I can just access state where I'd normally subscribe to this service. Is using the service file here valid, or am I taking the wrong approach for ngrx? If this isn't correct, what is the alternative?

You should not. Instead subcribe like this in your component

Example

I have service like this

```
  getPosts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  }
```

Then my effect to call the api

```
 getPosts$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(PostActions.LoadPosts),
      switchMap(_ => {
        return this.postService
          .getPosts()
          .pipe(
            map(
              (posts: IPost[]) => PostActions.LoadPostsSuccess({ posts }),
              catchError(errors => of(PostActions.LoadPostsFail(errors)))
            )
          );
      })
    )
  );
```

So in my container component

```
  public posts$: Observable<IPost[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<PostState>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(LoadPosts());
    this.posts$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectAllPosts));
  }

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3" *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">
    <div class="card card-container">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ post.body }}</p>
        <a
          class="btn btn-outline-primary"
          [routerLink]="['/posts/',post.id]"
          role="button"
          >Go to detail</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course you will need selector to get the data in your component

```
export const selectPostState = createFeatureSelector<PostState>(
  POST_FEATURE.storekey
);

export const selectPostsEntities = createSelector(
  selectPostState,
  posts => posts.entities //object look up
);

export const selectAllPosts = createSelector(
  selectPostsEntities,
  posts => Object.keys(posts).map(key => posts[key]) // use *ngFor
);
```